# What are holes? How they exist in pn junction

Tags: pn-junction

I always wonder that what are holes
I know electron and I can imagine it
But how holes exist...

Answer (score 6):

A hole exists where an electron should be... but isn't.

It's the absence of an electron.

> In physics, chemistry, and electronic engineering, an *electron hole* is the lack of an electron at a position where one could exist in an atom or atomic lattice. It is different from the positron, which is an actual particle of antimatter.
>
> *-- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_hole)*

When you dope the semiconductors for a P-N junction you add a dopant to the N portion which has an excess of electrons (more than would normally be there) and you add a dopant to the P portion which has a lack of electrons (less than would normally be there).

The electrons would be able to flow from the N to the P so they can occupy some of the holes in the P portion.

> After joining p-type and n-type semiconductors, electrons from the n region near the p–n interface tend to diffuse into the p region. As electrons diffuse, they leave positively charged ions (donors) in the n region. Likewise, holes from the p-type region near the p–n interface begin to diffuse into the n-type region, leaving fixed ions (acceptors) with negative charge. The regions nearby the p–n interfaces lose their neutrality and become charged, forming the space charge region or depletion layer
>
> *-- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%E2%80%93n_junction)*

Comment: Then with whom electrons combine at pn junction

Comment: They "fall into the holes" of the P doped area

Comment: Okk thanks can you tell me the concept of self sharing??

Comment: Not a term I am familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

Electron-hole pairs are created when an electron is excited to a higher energy state. This excited states causes it to be repelled away from the nucleus of an atom more. This is because the electron has taken on the energy of whatever excited it. This excited electron leaves behind a 'hole' of sorts, which is basically a void in the lower energy electron orbits. One can conceptually consider the hole as a positive charge, and in fact you can have a flow of positive charge by the migration of the hole through a lattice structure. After a certain period of time (spontaneous decay) the electron will relax back to it's original energy level, but due to the conservation of energy, the electron rids itself of the excess energy via emitting a photon (spontaneous emission) or a phonon (a quantized packet of vibrational energy/heat). In effect, a hole is the absence of an electron where one used to be. Semiconductors utilize the fact that different materials (dopents) contain a free electron or a missing electron to create doped regions explicitly defined as having more holes than electrons or vice-versa. N-doped regions are more negative, and P-doped regions are more positive. Their interaction behavior allows us to make things like transistors where the gate fills the holes and then allows mobile electrons to pass, otherwise no. We also utilize holes in semiconductor lasers and LED's where the bandgap (energy levels between electron orbits) are used to have a material emit photons more than phonons when an electron-hole pair recombine.